# Biggest and smallest value help me?

Tags: calculus

I have to find the maximum and minimum value of $f(x,y) = x^2+2xy-3y^2+y$ in the zone defined by the triangle with the vertices $O (0,0)$, $A(0,1)$ and $B(1,0)$.

So I first find the partial derivatives $f'(x)=2xy+2y=2xy+2y$ 
and $f'(y)=2xy+2x-6y+1$. We equal these and we have $y=0$ or $x=-1$. For $y=0$ we get $x=-1/2$ which isn't located inside the triangle and for $x=-1$, we again aren't inside the triangle.

Now we find 
$f(0;y)$,$f(x,0)$,$f(x,1-x)$...but how do I find these? do I just replace them in the very first equation?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your method of taking the partial derivatives...I get that $f_x = 2x + 2y$,  $f_y = 2x -6y +1$

Comment: moreover, you have to set $f_x=0$ and $f_y=0$ and not $f_x=f_y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are given:

$$f(x,y) = x^2+2xy-3y^2+y$$

Over the triangular region $D: (0,0), (1, 0), (0, 1)$.

Hints:

- Find $f_x$: $f_x = 2x + 2y$
- Find $f_y$: $f_y = 2x - 6y +1$
- Find the critical points, you should get one CP at: $(x, y) = \left(-\dfrac{1}{8}, \dfrac{1}{8}\right)$
- The function value at that point is $f(-1/8,1/8) = \dfrac{1}{16}$

Next, we are given a triangular region and need to consider the problem within that region only. You can define three line segments $(L_1, L_2, L_3)$ over this region.

- $L1: (0,0) ~\text{to}~ (0,1)$, here $x = 0$, so $f(x, y) = f(0, y) = -3y^2$.

Note that $x = 0, y \in (0,1)$ over this line segment, so what are the min and max for the function over this range?

- $L2: (1,0) ~\text{to}~ (0,1)$, here we get the line (we have two points and can find point-slope equation) $y = 1-x$, so $f(x, y) = f(x, 1-x) = x^2 + 2x (1-x) - 3(1-x)^2 + (1-x)$.

Note that $x \in (0,1), y \in (0,1)$, so what the min and max over this range for this function?

- $L3: (1,0) ~\text{to}~ (0,0)$, here $y = 0$, so $f(x, y) = f(x, 0) = x^2$.

Note that $x \in (0,1), y = 0$, so what the min and max over this range for this function?

After finding the extremum for each $L_i$, compare all three of them concurrently for the min and max and you are done.

Comment: I am in love with you.

Comment: @asfd: You are welcome and you are too kind! Please work through those details and make sure everything is clear! Regards

Comment: Amzoti there is a small mistake.When finding L1,it is -3y^2+y..

Comment: Also,the function value at (-1/8;1/8) isnt located in the range [0;1] so we dont consider it ,right? :D

Comment: @asfd: It is not inside the triangle, so no, we don't consider it. Be cautious with the "in the range" reasoning in two dimensions, though. For example, $(3/4,3/4)$ isn't inside (or even on an edge of) the triangle, even though $3/4$ is "in the range". To be inside the triangle, $(x,y)$ must satisfy all of the following inequalities: $$x>0\\y>0\\x+y<1$$

Comment: @asfd: It is not inside the triangular region, so no. Regards

Comment: Needs a TU! + 1

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks, has been a while since I did one of those, so it piqued my interest :-)! Currently trying to solve a simplex problem - getting close (been too long). I cannot believe how much stuff I used to be able to do and it is gone! ;-(

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be misunderstanding how to take the partial derivatives. These are basically just like derivatives in one variable, but here we just treat all variables but one as constants, and then derive normally in the other variable.

So in your case, let's take (for example) the partial derivative of $f(x,y)=x^2+2xy-3y^2+y$ with respect to $y$. Since derivatives split over sums, and constants factor out, then $$\begin{align}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}[f(x,y)] &= \frac{\partial}{\partial y}[x^2+2xy-3y^2+y]\\ &= \frac{\partial}{\partial y}[x^2]+\frac{\partial}{\partial}[2xy]+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}[-3y^2]+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}[y]\\ &= x^2\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial y}[1]+2x\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial y}[y]-3\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial y}[y^2]+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}[y]\\ &= x^2\cdot\frac{d}{dy}[1]+2x\cdot\frac{d}{dy}[y]-3\cdot\frac{d}{dy}[y^2]+\frac{d}{dy}[y]\\ &= x^2\cdot 0+2x\cdot 1-3\cdot 2y+1\\ &= 2x-6y+1.\end{align}$$

Similarly, we find that the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$ is $2x+2y.$

---

Now, to find extrema in the inside of the triangle, we set *both* partial derivatives equal to $0$ (not to each other), solve that system, and see which (if any) of the solutions found lie inside the triangle.

As for finding $f(0,y),f(x,0),$ and $f(x,1-x),$ we do indeed just plug into the formula. For example, $$\begin{align}f(x,1-x) &= x^2+2x(1-x)-3(1-x)^2+(1-x)\\ &= x^2+2x(1-x)-3(1-2x+x^2)+1-x\\ &= x^2+2x-2x^2-3+6x-3x^2+1-x\\ &= -4x^2+5x-2.\end{align}$$ The derivative of this is $-8x+5,$ which has a zero at $x=-\frac58,$ which lies within our interval of interest--namely $0<x<1$--so $(\frac58,\frac38)$ is a point we'll check. We'll do the same kind of thing with $f(0,y)$ (with $0<y<1$) and $f(x,0)$ (with $0<x<1$). Finally, we will also check the vertices $O,A,B.$